# QThread fails to use a QTimer properly

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qtimer

In my application, I have a custom QThread responsible for communicating with the backend, and call a utility function with a url and data from the run() method:

```
class SomeThread(QtCore.QThread):
  def __init__(self, parent=None...):
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)
    ...
  def run(self):
    final_desired_content = some_utility_method(url, data ...)
    # emitting success with final_desired_content
```

In the utility method(s), I'm making an http POST, getting a response back, parsing the response, and eventually passing the desired information to the above thread variable final_desired_content. Before I pass the information back, I am parsing some more information which I don't want to return, and would like to store in a SomeClass singleton instance:

```
def some_utility_method( ... ):
  ...
  return response_parsing(response)

def response_parsing(response):
  ...
  some_file.SomeClass.instance().setNewData(otherData)
  return mainParsedData
```

Because there may be multiple threads contacting the BE within a few seconds (specifically during the application start) I would like to prevent the writing of data before  has passed (it is ok that data we ignore is thrown away):

```
class SomeClass(QtCore.QObject):

  _instance = None

  @classmethod
  def instance(klass):
    if not klass._instance:
      klass._instance = SomeClass()
    return klass._instance

  def __init__(self):
    QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    self._recentlyUpdatedTimer = QtCore.QTimer()
    self._recentlyUpdatedTimer.setSingleShot(True)
    self._recentlyUpdatedTimer.timeout.connect(self._setOkToUpdateCB)
    self._storedData = None
    self._allowUpdate = True

  def _setOkToUpdateCB(self):
    self._allowUpdate = True

  def setNewData(self, newData):
    if self._allowUpdate:
      print "UPDATING!"
      self._allowUpdate = False
      self._storedData = newData
      self._recentlyUpdatedTimer.start(<some_time>)
    else:
      print "BLOCKED!" # ok to ignore newData
```

The problem is that this successfully updates once, then after the second update succeeds, I am getting this error: QObject::startTimer: Timers cannot be started from another thread

From what I know and read about threads, the run() in the QThread is another thread, that might not know what has been happening in the main thread. 
Debugging, it appears that the timer is still running, even though it is set to singleShot.

I will appreciate any suggestions :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by not using a timer.
What I ended up doing was:

```
class SomeClass(QtCore.QObject):
  ...
  DATA_EXPIRE_THRESHOLD = 3
  ...
  def __init__(self):
    ...
    self._counter = 0 # Just for debugging
    self._dataExpireTime = None
    self._data = None

  def setNewData(self, new_data):
    self._counter += 1
    if self._dataExpireTime is None or self._isExpired():
      print "self._isExpired(): [%s], counter: [%s]" % (self._isExpired(), self.counter)
      self._data = new_data
      self._dataExpireTime = time.time() + self.DATA_EXPIRE_THRESHOLD

  def _isExpired(self):
    return time.time() >= self._dataExpireTime
```

so setting the threshold to three seconds, the output is:

```
self._isExpired(): [True], counter: [1] 
self._isExpired(): [True], counter: [2]
self._isExpired(): [True], counter: [6]
self._isExpired(): [True], counter: [15]
self._isExpired(): [True], counter: [17]
self._isExpired(): [True], counter: [18]
```

I was trying to use a mutex, but it had a similar issue to the timer.
I would still appreciate an explanation, or advice to dealing with such issues.